# Google Analytics Enhanced E-Commerce

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

in our webshop we are currently using the enhanced ecommerce object.
Atm the attribute price is used, but we are selling services.
So we made a second attribute lets name it completePrice , which is the price multiplied by the times the customer has to pay in this specific contract.

How can we use this second attribute as the price used in Google Analytics E-Commerce?

Comment: You can't, unless you specify it in a custom metric with the value you want. Same with any other attribute that does not comply with the standard EE product object parameters, you'll have to either configure custom dimensions or metrics for those.

Comment: Thanks, in that case i'll overwrite the price var with the completePrice value..

Comment: Perfect. That'll do the trick.

Comment: your comment can be used as answer if you wish, it is the answer to my question really :D